# Upload Image To Cloudinary Using Java API

Tags: cloudinary

I am using cloudinary API with JAVA. We have a requirement to upload images with an auto increasing number automatically. Like 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg...

- When I upload the first image(**abc.jpg**) so it would become **1.jpg**.
- When I upload the second image(**xyz.jpg**) so it would become **2.jpg**. Same for others.

**does cloudinary provide any kind of solution for this situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported, this is something that you need to manage by yourself.

Maybe you can rename any uploaded image after receiving the notification URL on your server, but you need to keep in mind stuff like async actions...

Best,
Yakir